# Request Validation with Laravel 5.3 for Multiple rows

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

My Request File rules are

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
    'mobile' => 'required',
    'code' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

My input data can be a simple => for which the request validation is working fine.

```
  {
    "mobile":"81452569",
    "code":"4858"
}
```

My input data can be a complex too => for which the request validation is not working  fine.

```
[{
    "mobile":"81452569",
    "code":"4858"
},
{
    "mobile":"81452570",
    "code":"4858"
}]
```

How to validate for multiple rows with request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sent it all in array to the request object like so:

```
"data" => [
  [
    "mobile" => "81452569",
    "code" => "4858"
  ],
  [
     "mobile" =>"81452570",
     "code" =>"4858"
  ]
];
```

Then in your validation rules do this:

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        'data.*.mobile' => 'required',
        'data.*.code' => 'required',
    ];
 }
```

Comment: You rocked bro with simple answer. But the message output is coming as ["The data.0.mobile field is required."]. Any solution to simple make as Mobile field is required.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene sure, you can override the messages() function inside the request class: `public function messages() { return [ 'data.*.mobile' => 'Some error here', 'data.*.code' => 'Another error here' ]; }`